# Opening a new tab to read a PDF file

Tags: html

I am probably missing something simple here, however i will ask anyway. I have made a link to open up a PDF file, however it opens up in the current tab rather than a new one. What code shall i use in HTML to open a new tab to read the PDF file.

```
<div class="footer_box_content">
    <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
    <p>Many  thanks  to  everyone  who cleared snow and ice during the cold spell in February.
    Should Arctic conditions return, each block has a shovel and a jar of rock salt  to  clear  the  steps. 
    Please click more to read the full newsletter.</p>
    <div class="button_01"><a href="newsletter_01.pdf">Read more</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open link in a new tab in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-a-new-tab-in-html)

Answer (score 64):

```
<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_blank">Read more</a>
```

Target _blank will force the browser to open it in a new tab or window (depending on user browser settings).

Comment: Nope. If the user has set their browser to do something different with PDF files (like download them) it won't open in a new tab. There's no way to guarantee a PDF to open in a new browser window.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt Where did I state that this is guaranteed to open the page in a new window?

Comment: Quote: `Target _blank will force the browser to open it in a new window`. That's simply not true. You cannot force a browser to open a PDF. It may simply be downloaded, depending on the user's settings, even with the target attribute set to "_blank". See my answer below.

Comment: Force != guaranteed :)

Comment: There is no way to force a browser to open a PDF in a new window.

Answer (score 59):

As everyone else has pointed out, this **can** work:

```
<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_blank">Read more</a>
```

But what nobody has pointed out is that **it's not guaranteed to work**.

There is no way to force a user's browser to open a PDF file in a new tab. Depending on the user's browser settings, even with `target="_blank"` the browser may react the following ways:

1. Ask for action
2. Open it in  Adobe Acrobat
3. Simply download the file directly to their computer

Take a look at Firefox's settings, for example:

[image]

Chrome has a similar setting:

[image]

If the user has chosen to "Save File" in their browsers settings when encountering a PDF, there is no way you can override it.

Comment: at least can we detect that and use fallback?

Comment: @ParthibanRajendran No. You cannot detect the user's settings, but even if there was, you could still not override their settings.

Answer (score 7):

An observation, `_blank` alone will not make sure the file is opened in a new tab. The response header for the file request should have `Content-Type : application/pdf`.

Try this [link](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf), it will open the file in new tab as the server provide required headers.

Same is the case for other file types also. For ex: video files get request should have proper `Content-Type` like `video/mp4`.

Comment: This helped me, I had response header coming as `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` which was downloading the pdf automatically that I didn’t want. 
`Content-Type : application/pdf` is what I needed it to be.

Comment: "Try this link, it will open the file in new tab"... Not for me in FireFox. It's still opening in the same tab.

Comment: This 'link' does not open in a tab for me; how do you apply the Content-Type to this HTML content?

Comment: Every file served by a server will have a Content-Type header. It will be either manually set as per need or derived form file type. And link not opening in new tab in all browsers, I assume there's browser specific settings for file types. In chrome desktop it actually opens in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use target attribute

```
<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `target` on your tag `<a>`

```
<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_blank">Read more</a>
```

The target attribute specifies where to open the link.
Using "_blank" will make your browser to open a new window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<a>` tag like this:

```
<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_blank">
```

You can find more about the `target` attribute **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)**.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome this has proven to work well for me.

```
<a href="newsletter_01.pdf" target="_new">Read more</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, someone has already mentioned that we can force the browser to open pdf file in new tab by using `target`, but depending on user's browser setting it may force to download instead of opening and I see most of the browser's settings are like so in default.

The easiest way I found is, using **Google Drive**. We can upload the document in drive and change the setting that anyone with the link can view the doc. Use that link like below:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQHmS" target="_blank">
```

When we click the link, the doc will open in the new tab from drive.

Answer (score -3):

Try this, it worked for me.

`<td><a href="Docs/Chapter 1_ORG.pdf" target="pdf-frame">Chapter-1 Organizational</a></td>`

Comment: More information is needed to understand what this does and why it might work. Please consider explaining your answer.