# Need to link a website to the "OK" button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not really well-versed with codes and I just wanted to try this out for my team.  What I have is just a simple code that pops up an alert message (with OK button) everytime we open our Google Spreadsheet.  What I wanted to happen is when we click "OK", it will open a link in a new tab.  Here's my "script editor" code:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Welcome to HAVENLY Offshore Team Workspace! Check out our CONFLUENCE updates today!');
}
```

Please help me achieve my ultimate goal here, I've been trying to find a solution for hours already.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: not possible like that. build instead a little webapp dialog and have the user click an anchor. show us your attempts at that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you use a custom dialog instead of an `alert`. Custom dialogs are much more powerful by allowing you to define your own html. Just create the following files in the script attached to the sheet.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  openWelcomeDialog();
}

function openWelcomeDialog() {
  // get the html from the file called "Pages.html"
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pages');

  // open the dialog
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModelessDialog(html, "Welcome to HAVENLY Offshore Team Workspace!")
}
```

**Pages.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- target="_blank" directs the link to a new blank tab -->
    <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html">
      Check out our CONFLUENCE updates today!
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Update**
You can also close the dialog when the user clicks on the link with an `onclick` event handler:

```
<a onclick="google.script.host.close()" target="_blank" href="||url||">
  Check out our CONFLUENCE updates today!
</a>
```

Comment: Thnx for the solution. It needs one correction: instead of 'HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Welcome')' it should state 'HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Pages'). Now I'm looking for a way to have a 'href = URL'-link, where URL is a spreadsheet just created in the previous lines of code in my script. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user Hmmm, it would be good to make the URL dynamic. I'll add an update to the question later today.

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thnx in advance!

Comment: @user Solved, however I think the Dynamic Spreadsheet Link should have its own question. It's related to the current question but doesn't really belong among its answers.

Comment: @user If you want to write the question, I can answer if you notify me.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onOpen(){
  confluencePopup()
}

function confluencePopup(){
  // will display the dialog box with html text
  var text = "Welcome to HAVENLY Offshore Team Workspace! Check out our CONFLUENCE updates today!'"
  var url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888267/need-to-link-a-website-to-the-ok-button"
  var rawHTML = '<a onclick="google.script.host.close()" target="_blank" href="' + String(url) + '">' + text + '</a>'
  var htmlSerivce = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(rawHTML)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModelessDialog(htmlSerivce, "Welcome")
}
```

Change the `url` to your link, and `text` to the anchor text you would like. You can then just call this function in your `onOpen()` function. When run it will display a popup with your anchor text, and link to your page.

You may need to configure permissions to run the pop-up. See [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) for that information. Simply you need to add oauthScopes to your `appsscript.json` file.

Edit: this can be altered to change the link dynamically with a variable, and does not require an additional file to run.