# How to open the link clicked in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, href

In my page,I have a link on which i clicked it should open in a new tag but its not working for me.Can anyone please suggest help.So far I hadd tried the below

```
         <a target="_BLANK" ng-href="{{news.url}}">{{news.url}}</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open link in new tab on html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use href instead of ng-href

```
<a target="_blank" href="google.co.in">google.co.in</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`target="{{condition ? '_blank' : '_self'}}"` should do it

In your case do:

```
<a target="{{condition ? '_blank' : '_self'}}" ng-href="{{news.url}}">{{news.url}}</a>
```

Comment: try this `<a ng-attr-target="{{(condition) ? '_blank' : undefined}}" ng-href="{{news.url}}">{{news.url}}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `<a target="_BLANK" href="{{news.url}}">{{news.url}}</a>` instead of `ng-href`.