# Open a hyperlink in a new window or tab c#?

Tags: c#, html

I have below which is C# string builder code and currrently when the user clicks the hyperlink it opens it in the background, I need it to open in a new tab or perhaps a window once hyperlink is clicked. Please advise

```
sb.Append("<td><a href=\"" + baseMMPUrlConfigValue + "/profile/supplier/" + organisation.Id + "\">Profile Link</a></td>");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto please edit code

Comment: as per the duplicate, `target="_blank"` is your friend. This attribute will cause the link to open in a new tab or window (as per the user's settings, which you cannot control). Surprised you didn't find this by searching online already

Comment: Like this? sb.Append("<td><a target="_blank" href=\"" + baseMMPUrlConfigValue + "/profile/supplier/" + organisation.Id + "\">Profile Link</a></td>");

Comment: yep that looks right

Comment: Yes, although being within a C# string you might need to escape the quote marks (or use single quotes in the HTML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the above line in your code with the line below and this should do the magic for you.

```
sb.Append("<td><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" + baseMMPUrlConfigValue + "/profile/supplier/" + organisation.Id + "\">Profile Link</a></td>");
```