# javascript function is not displaying anchor tag

Tags: web

```js
let css_pdf_zero = ['cssFoundations.pdf', 'cssCookBook.pdf'];
           
            function pdf_load_zero(pdf, path){
            path = path || 'pdf-testing/'; // default path here
                 var pdfAnchor = '<a href="' + path + '" alt = "">' + '</a>';
                document.write(pdfAnchor); document.close();
            }
            $('#tabs-one1').html(pdf_load_zero(css_pdf_zero));
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with document.write?

Comment: Yeah that's just a mistake but even still it doesn't work if you remove it

Answer (score 0):

Is this closer to what you are trying to do?

```js
let css_pdf_zero = ['cssFoundations.pdf', 'cssCookBook.pdf'];
           
function pdf_load_zero(pdf, path){
  path = path || 'pdf-testing/'; // default path here
  var pdfAnchor = '<a href="' + path + '" alt="">Text</a>';
  $('#tabs-one1').html(pdfAnchor);
}

pdf_load_zero(css_pdf_zero);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-one1"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah but it jumps to this window saying at the top Index of /pdf-testing, is there a way I can open a pdf in a separate window to read.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html