# how can i make a random link open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue making a "random" link open up in a new tab.

```
      var randomLink = function(){

  var links = [
    'youtube.com/channel/UCkq10sWOK1ftebGZPFJBekA',
    'soundcloud.com/iamcardib',
    'soundcloud.com/rickybobby-slumpgod',
    'soundcloud.com/wavey-hefner',
    'soundcloud.com/liluzivert',
    'soundcloud.com/flameemojimusic',
    'soundcloud.com/youngthugworld',
    'soundcloud.com/kodak-black'

  ];


  var max = (links.length)

 window.open=links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max]

  var link = links[randomNumber];
  window.location = "http://" + link;

};
```

I've multiple times to get the links to open up in a new tab when I click a button but it will only open in the same tab.

Comment: `window.open=links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max]` I think you are missing a close bracket on this line

Comment: @Amy — Not a duplicate of that. That is about a link opening in a new tab and the answers focus on using plain HTML rather then using JS as you need for a random URL like this question is asking about.

Comment: @Quentin - JavaScript answer is also present in the suggested duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33546457/477420. So far it is very unclear what you are having trouble with (short of some strange `window.open=links...` syntax)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov — I am not jaystang.

Answer (score 1):

[`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is a **function**. You need to **call** it, not assign a new value to it.

You also have a syntax error. A `)` is missing.

```
window.open(links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) is `window.open(stuff)` not `window.open=stuff`, because `window.open` is a function.

As @Quentin said,

> [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
>   is a **function**. You need to **call** it, not assign a new value to it.

Functions are called like this: `functionName(parameters);`

Values are assigned like this: `variableName=value;`

Also, you are missing a close bracket and a semicolon. If you apply these,

```
window.open=links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max]
```

becomes

```
window.open(links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max)]);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you added nothing from what Quentin had already said

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro Oh ok. I didn't notice his answer, I was already typing mine.

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro I spotted the error and commented on the OP's post you see

Answer (score -3):

I think it should be `window.open=links[Math.floor(Math.random()*max)]`

Comment: that won't work try running it in the console before you answer