# JS Jquery - Open a link in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this JS in my website to display a custom text message, and the message has a hyperlink. However, it opens it in the current window and I want to make sure it opens in a new tab. I cannot figure out how to achieve that in these circumstances.

```
var conceptName = jQuery('#pa_analise_objeto').find(":selected").val();
if(conceptName=='sem_revisao') {
    jQuery("#displayCustomMsg").html("<p>The model will be <br/>printed automatically <a href='https://LINK.HERE.COM' style='color: #202020;'><u>verificação manual</u></a></p>");
}
```

Comment: use  target="_blank"  if it is show in your div "displayCustomMsg"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `target='_blank'` attribute to `<a>` tag.

```
var conceptName = jQuery('#pa_analise_objeto').find(":selected").val();
  if(conceptName=='sem_revisao'){
     jQuery("#displayCustomMsg").html("<p>The model will be <br/>printed automatically <a target='_blank' href='https://LINK.HERE.COM' style='color: #202020;'><u>verificação manual</u></a></p>");
     }
```

Comment: Did you try this answer @Jaime Matos?

Comment: Awesome, so that was just HTML, easier than I thought it would be. Thank you a million

Comment: Your welcome. happy to help. Can you accept my answer @JaimeMatos?

Answer (score 1):

Add `target="_blank"` to your anchor tag, it'll open a new tab.

```
<a target="_blank" href='https://LINK.HERE.COM' style='color: #202020;'><u>verificação manual</u></a>
```