# Opening links in new tabs for wiki pages in TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, markdown

I'm currently developing wiki pages in TFS 2018 via Markdown. But as far as I know, there appears to be no way to create a link on a wiki page that opens within a new tab. All links created open in the existing tab.  I read through the [wiki documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/index?view=vsts).  I also reported it to be an [official feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/374253/allow-wiki-page-links-to-open-in-new-tab.html).  But does anyone have any tricks or hacks I could implement in order to get that going for now?

**Update**
: I have tried basic html such as:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google Link</a>
```

But when I click save and view that link in Chrome Developer Tools, TFS 2018 is stripping out the `target="_blank"`.  Any possible reasons why TFS would do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with how TFS creates links, but in Markdown any feature not supported can be implemented with raw HTML. In your Markdown, just include a raw HTML link to the page which opens in a new tab: `<a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>`. See [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17711146/866026)

Comment: when I place that in a wiki page and click save, and then inspect the code from developer tools, TFS removes target="_blank" from that link.

Comment: It is not uncommon for various tools to sanitize HTML for "security concerns" and/or to have more control over the "user experience". Disabling the ability to open in a separate tab seems to fall into the later which suggests this was a conscious decision. In other words, the option is intentionally not supported.

Comment: hmm...I totally get the concept of delivering a default standard with a product OOTB.  But if the tool is then purchased and managed by a corporate entity, then there should be some flexibly in allowing that group to determine what a security concern is (i.e. here are settings to adjust what we recommend by default).  That seems reasonable.  Hopefully this was an overlook.

Answer (score 1):

I tried now in Azure DevOps and it opens a new tab:

```
[Google](https://www.google.com)
```

[image]

Update:

It works only in Azure DevOps and not in TFS 2018.

Comment: Hmm...There must be a configuration setting that allows you to do that because it still opens in the same tab for me.

Comment: I didn't change any settings, do you have the little icon with the arrow near the link?

Comment: Yes, but the arrow icon itself it not clickable.  Only the words to the left of the icon is clickable.  When I click the word, it opens within the existing tab.

Comment: I just checked in our TFS 2018 and you right, it doesn't work and also if I add `target="_blank"` he removed it.

Comment: So maybe...there is a chance in a future release that TFS will incorporate this feature, due to Azure DevOps already having it.

Comment: Yea, I really hope.