# Why is the value of "base rel=" ignored?

Tags: html, referrer

I want to add 'noreferrer' to all the links on my static html page, without having to worry about forgetting to add it to some new link in the future. I tried using `base rel="noreferrer"` [as occasionally suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33545841/597720) but it doesn't seem to work. With this simple page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base rel="noreferrer">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="linktest.html">no rel</a>
    <br />
    <a rel="noreferrer" href="linktest.html">rel</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

and using Chromium 73 on Debian 9 (stable), when I click on the first link the access log shows a referrer:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2019:11:32:02 -0700] "GET /linktest.html HTTP/1.1" 304 330 "https://www.example.com/linktest.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36"
```

but not when I click the second link, that had `rel="noreferrer"` explicitly specified:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2019:11:32:06 -0700] "GET /linktest.html HTTP/1.1" 304 330 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36"
```

I also tried adding `target="_blank"` to the `base` tag but it didn't change the referrer behavior, just forced the links to open in a new tab by default (which I don't want).

Should this work? If so, why doesn't this work?

Is there a way (preferably without using javascript) to force all links from a page to suppress the referrer, that will work at least with my browser and preferably with most modern browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```html
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

That’s [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name), but I haven’t been able to verify that it works.

The `base` element does not have a `rel` attribute according to the specs.