# How To Open a new Tab by passing some argument into URL

Tags: browser

If somebody click on link that should have some parameters in url to open the link in new tab.

for example : www.youtube.com/c/devtechsolutions

will just navigate to this link.

What if I would like to open this link in new tab, just by modifying the url with someparameters.

Only url has to be modified.

Comment: This may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html

Comment: No, above link is about editing the html tags and I am asking about to open a new tab by editing the url in browser.

Comment: A "URL" is a resource location. Ultimately the web browser program is in charge of deciding when to open new tabs.  The accepted way to communicate to browsers to open a new tab is `target="_blank"` in the `a` tag as answered in the linked question.

Comment: I go to seat here, I got same problem, how and what to add to 'https://example.com/' to open in new tab,