# How to make a link open in a new tab

Tags: html, wordpress, button, hyperlink

This is the code currently, I've tried adding `target="_Blank"` but it still opens in the same tab.

We are using WordPress and this is the code we use in the text box for a button to appear.

```
button color="extra-color-1" hover_text_color_override="#ffffff" size="large" url="https://www.insideeducation.ca/learning-resources/classroom-learning-resources/elementary-school/#flying-animals-scavenger-hunt"  text="Flying Animals | Scavenger Hunt"]
```

Comment: have you tried `target="_blank"` with a lower case b?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include three different ideas for you. Do any of them work?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you that any of these approaches will work for sure, but there are three methods or workarounds I've thought of that you could try out.

### 1. Use `target="_blank"`

I would usually use lower case letters in target attributes. So instead of `target="_Blank"`, you could try `target="_blank"`.

However, this is more likely to be a matter of preference, and I think browsers will most likely accept both of these options.

### 2. Use some simple javascript

You could use the javascript `window.open()` function as a workaround for this problem.

Replace `target="_Blank"` with `onclick="window.open('https://www.example.com')"` and see if that works any better!

### 3. Use an anchor tag

At the moment, you seem to be using a `button` element which looks something like this:

```
<button color="extra-color-1" ... target="_blank" url="https://...">
  Click here!
</button>
```

You could wrap an `a` tag around the button and instead apply the `target` attribute to that. It may be that `target` attributes work better directly on anchor tags. Here's what it would look like:

```
<a href="https://..." target="_blank">
  <button color="extra-color-1" ... >
    Click here!
  </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try anchor tag because i think target attribute works pretty well with anchor