# Need Links Within iFrame to Redirect in Another Tab

Tags: html

I have a super simple website-- It consists simply of ten links that I want to be linking externally, away from my site, preferably in a new tab and not just within the iFrame that GoDaddy's website builder is forcing sites to open within. I am not experienced with HTML at all, and frankly just started teaching myself today. This same problem is what I think is also causing these links, when clicked on my phone, to not work at all. If there is anything I can add to the HTML code which will fix these linkings, that would be wonderful. If you would like to see what I'm talking about, you can visit my site [HERE](https://alexpoe.com) and try for yourself. Thank you so much for any and all help anyone is able to provide.

```
<STYLE>A {text-decoration: none;} </STYLE>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/1mjAVXxfCzr6Cjeq79lzqs?si=DYVFnBiwS9eCMJkAKRWPTw" style="color: #ffffff;">music</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8CdhPfaDP0I5pEU7yqAaNA/" style="color: #ffffff;">youtube</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://letterboxd.com/alexpoe134" style="color: #ffffff;">letterboxd</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://last.fm/user/alexanderpoe" style="color: #ffffff;">last.fm</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://codewars.com/users/alexpoe134" style="color: #ffffff;">codewars</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://instagram.com/alexpoe134" style="color: #ffffff;">instagram</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://twitter.com/alexpoe134" style="color: #ffffff;">twitter</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://snapchat.com/add/alexpoe134" style="color: #ffffff;">snapchat</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://facebook.com/musicbypoe" style="color: #ffffff;">facebook</a></span></h2>
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://patreon.com/alexpoe134" style="color: #ffffff;">patreon</a></span></h2>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Comment: Also if the answers were helpful, you should consider accepting the one you like best by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add target to the link:

```
<a href="...." target="_blank">text</a>
```

[`<a>: The Anchor element - HTML: Hypertext Markup Language | MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>Use target="_blank" to open the linked document in a new browser window or tab:</p>

<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Visit Google!</a>
```

## HTML Links - The target Attribute

### target attribute can have one of the following values:

- _self - Default. Opens the document in the same window/tab as it was clicked
- _blank - Opens the document in a new window or tab
- _parent - Opens the document in the parent frame
- _top - Opens the document in the full body of the window

[For Your Question](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

[For HTML Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"` to the all the `<a>` tags that you want to open in a new tab