# How to open link in new tab from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, window.open

I'm trying to have items in a dropdown list open in new tab using the javascript function below. As of now, a drop-down list is displayed from where each item will open only in the same window.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Button Name</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="">Choice A</a>
  <a href="">Choice B/a>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript at all. Just set the `target` attribute to `_blank` in your `<a>` tags like so:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.show{
  display:block !important;
}
#myDropdown{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Button Name</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="https://choice.a" target="_blank">Choice A</a>
  <a href="https://choice.b" target="_blank">Choice B</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to duplicates

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for the duplicate question. I guess I wanted to see if there was a way to do it through the function using the .open method or something but this solves my problem nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `target` attribute with value `_blank` to your `a` tags.

Like this:

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to duplicates, and please [don't use, recommend or link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).