# How to open a link in a new Tab in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

How can i open a link in a new Tab in NextJS ? i tried this :

```
      <Link href="https://twitter.com/" passHref>
        <a target="_blank">
          <div className={`${dark ? styles.iconTwitterWhite : styles.iconTwitter} mr-3`} />
        </a>
      </Link>
```

It opens the link in a new Tab but i have an `ESLint` message saying :

```
ESLint: The href attribute is required for an anchor to be keyboard accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide an href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles.
```

Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: That's the correct way to open in a new tab, but make sure to add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to [prevent the newly opened tab from being able to modify the original tab maliciously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html). Regarding the linting issue, it's a known limitation of Next.js `<Link>` component. See possible solutions here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5533

Answer (score 172, accepted):

As this is an external link, you don't need to use Link

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <div className={`${dark ? styles.iconTwitterWhite : styles.iconTwitter} mr-3`} />
 </a>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to get this done for the same website. What if I want another URL opened in a new tab? And before you ask me, yes, I have a valid use case.

Comment: @ankush981 That's what the `target="_blank"` attribute is doing here - a new tab will be opened (or a new window, if the user's browser preferences dictate that instead).

Comment: Also, adding a comment to highlight the importance of the `rel="noopener noreferrer"` properties for any new tab links. https://www.reliablesoft.net/noreferrer-noopener/

Comment: I have come back to look at this same answer on like 10 different occasions.

Comment: sometimes you don't know if a link will be internal or external and have to cover both cases, so the answers below which explain how to do this with <Link /> are going to be more flexible and more robust than this answer.

Answer (score 71):

**Nov. 2022 Answer:**

With the release of Next 13, the `<Link/>` component now renders a `<a/>` tag internally, so you no longer have to add a child `<a/>` tag.

This means that in order to open a link in a new tab, you should be able to do the following:

`<Link href="https://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"> Google </Link>`

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't realize this was a thing. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't solve it, link opens in the same tab

Comment: @kag359six, if we need to open a page within our next-reactjs app on a new tab, is it possible to do this using router.push?

Comment: @jsN00b I don't believe so, but I'm not sure why you would need to. `router.push` is only useful in the context of the currently open tab.

Comment: "why you would need to." in spite of informing the management that React is supposed to be SPA (single page app), they want to allow user to open a new window (pointing to a "page" within the app). My tech-lead & I informed them that it will cause problem with state-mgmt - but it fell on deaf-ears.

Comment: @jsN00b Understood. You could work around that by passing query parameters in the URL to restore state in that newly opened window. But either way you wouldn't use `router.push`

Answer (score 53):

I've heard there are cases where you want to stick with `Link` (i18n stuff that `Link` helps with) so you can use `passHref` (which just passes the `href` to the immediate child) like so:

```
<Link href="/" passHref>
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    Foo
  </a>
</Link>
```

Comment: didn't work unless I added target="_blank" to Link like:
```
<Link href={href}  target='_blank' >
```

Comment: Can you provide a source on where "you've heard"?

Comment: Sorry @kiru I can't remember what it was, but I distinctly remember I used to be on the _"a normal anchor tag is fine"_ team until I ran into something that made me change my mind.

Comment: @kiru https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#passhref

Answer (score 21):

> The path in my project: public/NameFile/NamePdf.pdf
>
> > Note: 1) Don't forget the dependence for "Link" => import Link from 'next/link'
> > 2) As you can see, I did not put "public" in the  link. >>          Because you simply don't need to put it because NextJs is smart .

```
      <Link href="./NameFile/NamePdf.pdf" download>
          <a target="_blank">
              {your code ......}
          </a>
      </Link>
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for

Answer (score 9):

I tried the below code snippet and it's working without nor errors. Otherwise, my localhost works with no errors but when I"m deploy to the Vercel it's getting errors in the build log. So I tried this code snippet and it's working localhost as well as the vercel.

```html
<Link href="https://twitter.com/">
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" className='link-item'>
    <div className={`${dark ? styles.iconTwitterWhite : styles.iconTwitter} mr-3`} />
  </a>
</Link>
```

make sure to add `target="_blank"` and `rel="noopener noreferrer"` attribute into `a` tag.

Answer (score 9):

On the next.js 13 version, you can use this.

```
<Link href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank"> Facebook </Link>
```

Answer (score 8):

Since **Next13**, the <Link> component should NOT have <a> child. So you cannot put the target there, instead, set it on the <Link> like:

```
    <Link
      href="/some-route"
      className="some classes"
      target="_blank"
    >
      {children}
    </Link>
```

However, if you insist on using <a> inside of the Link, you need to pass the legacyBehavior prop:

```
<Link href="/about" legacyBehavior>
  <a>About Us</a>
</Link>
```

Check on the next [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-tag)

Answer (score 7):

**Use next router**

This method is used with a client-side transition, to move the content of the page in another direction. This kind of behaviour is useful for navigating your page to another tab.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

export default function App() {     

   const openInNewTab = (url) => {
       const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
       if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
   }
 
    
   return (
      <div onClick={() => openInNewTab("/path")}>                                           
         Button
      </div>
   )

}
```

Comment: Would you please let me know what happens if you remove the `import` from the above snippet? Seems like the `useRouter` is imported, but not used in this context.

Comment: You only need the "useRouter" using the "router.push" function to open a page. This will open the page in the current tab. For example  "<div  onClick={() => router.push("/aboutus")}>". We create a new custom method "openInNewTab"  which replaces "router.push" for links you want to open in new tabs. You don't have to import otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the NextJs link use to move other page of current web without reload right?

So in this case you want to go external link which not exist in you web so you don't need to use Link provided by NextJs. You can use any other link.

**For Example:**

1. Vanilla HTML anchor tag
2. React-Bootstrap Link
3. Chakra-UI Link

and there are so many libraries out there.

Answer (score 3):

Use a vanilla  tag. Next Link is for efficiently navigating between your own pages, not for navigating to external pages like twitter, LinkedIn, etc.

Example:

```
<a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/youraccount/'> My LinkedIn </a>
```

Comment: What if I want to open one of my own pages in a new tab?

Comment: In this case you would also use an <a> tag, not Next Link. This is because opening another tab does a full load of the page therefore removing any efficiency benefits that Next Link was built for.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Next13, you can use target props with NextJS Link.

```
<Link
  href="/page-link"
  target="_blank"
>
  {children}
</Link>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using nextJs 14 then you can do like this

```
<Link href={"https://www.apple.com/"} target="_blank"> Appple </Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js 14.0.1, you can utilize the `<Link>` component to create links. Within the `Link` tag, there is an attribute called `target`. By using `target="_blank"`, you can open the link in a new tab. If you omit the `target` attribute, the link will open in the same tab.

```
<Link href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank">
    <div className={`${dark ? styles.iconTwitterWhite : styles.iconTwitter} mr-3`} />
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't directly control the opening of links in new tabs like you would with traditional HTML anchor tags (). Instead, you typically use the built-in Link component to navigate between pages and let the browser handle how the link is opened based on user preferences.

```
<Link href="/other-page" passHref>
 <a  target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Go to Other Page</a>
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Next13, you can do this without the need for an anchor tag :

```
  <Link href="https://twitter.com/" passHref target="_blank" >
      <div className={`${dark ? styles.iconTwitterWhite : 
       styles.iconTwitter} mr-3`} />
  </Link>
```

Answer (score -1):

in next 13 i can do it like this

```
          <Link
            target="_black"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            href={"https://www.instagram.com/"}
          >
            <AiOutlineInstagram
              className="h-8 hover:text-gray-500 w-8 bg-green-50 rounded-xl p-2 hover:shadow-xl"
              title=""
            />
          </Link>
```