# How to pass parameters from Pug to Backend JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I have this pug page and I need to open the link to a new window.
The link is dynamic because it is populated from the backend and when I click the link, I want to open it in a new tab.

How do I do it ?

layout.pug

```
a(href='/goto/?url='+url)
```

main.js

```
app.get('/goto/?url=:url', (req, res) => {
    var new_tab_url = req.params.url;
    window.open(new_tab_url, '_blank').focus();
});
```

I need to pass the URL from **layout.pug** to **main.js** to open a new tab.
But I keep getting error

```
Cannot GET /goto/
```

Or perhaps , is there other simpler way ?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to pass the link to your router? Just navigate to it in a new window, like in HTML. Pug just compiles to HTML.

Comment: My bad, this topic has been closed. The issue has been resolved. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

To open a link in a new window, just use this:

```
a(href= url, target='_blank')
```

There's no reason to pass a variable to a backend router or try to handle the redirection server-side. Just use [`target="_blank"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-a-new-tab-in-html).

Answer (score -1):

My bad. This topic is closed since the issue has been resolved.

I am using Express (Node.JS) and this is what I do :

layout.pug

```
a(href='/goto/?url='+url)
```

main.js

```
app.get('/goto', (req, res) => {
    var new_tab_url = req.query.url;
    res.redirect(new_tab_url);
});
```

At least this works on my issue.

Using :
NodeJS Express and Pug