# Make a hyperlink in chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome Extension with some links, but when I click the link, they don't open the expected site. I need when a link is clicked it opens a new tab with the link, like if a hyperlink with **https://www.google.com/** what it should do:

1. Open a new tab
2. In the new tab, open the link **https://www.google.com/**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Selenideium Element Inspector</h2>
<div>
    <p>A handy tool to log attributes and Selenide, Selenium, Cypress, Playwright, TestCafe, Squish locators of the clicked element.
        You can save dozens of minutes each day by using this plugin.</p>
    <p>
        Usage:<br>
    </p>
    <ol>
        <li>Install the plugin</li>
        <li>Open a page</li>
        <li>Open DevTools</li>
        <li>Open console</li>
        <li>Enable permanent log in the console's settings to prevent clearing the console on page change</li>
        <li>Click on an element</li>
        <li>Select the most nice-looking selector</li>
        <li>Copy-paste it into your favourite IDE</li>
        <li>Go to step 6.</li>
    </ol>
    <p>
        Do you have any feedback? Do you miss a feature? Submit it on <a href="https://github.com/mszeles/selenideium-element-inspector/issues">GitHub.</a>
    </p>

    <p>Created by <a href="https://mszeles.com">Miki Szeles</a>.</p>
    <p>Show your support by <a href="https://buymeacoffee.com/mikiszeles">buying a Coffee for me</a> in case this extension makes your work easier</p>
    <small>Have fun!</small>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the link not work at all (like a 404 error)? Or does it just not open in a new tab. Because to open a link in a new tab set `target="_blank"` as an attribute on the link.

Comment: Does not open a new tab

Comment: Ok, can you give a sample?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open link in a new tab in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-a-new-tab-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `target="_blank"` attribute-

```
<p>Created by <a href="https://mszeles.com" target="_blank">Miki Szeles</a>.</p>
```