# How can I force a hyperlink to open in a new tab without using HTML?

Tags: hyperlink

I have an image.  The image is linked to another site.  I would like to the user to be able to click that image and for the link to open in a new tab so that the user doesn't have to re-open the document every time they click a link.

I tried turning the image itno a pdf but could not locate the document scripts.  My Adobe might be too old.

ETA:  The image is hosted on a site where I do not control the html.  It is on a marketplace. I would like to link it to a free sample that opens in a new tab so that the user won't lose the site where they can make the purchase.

Comment: [This is available in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/). Why would you refuse to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I have added the answer in HTML below as you have not clarified whether you don't want to use this because you're using another programming language.

If you are attempting to do this in another program or programming language. Please add the appropriate tags to your OP as well as the program/language you are trying to use.

### Answer using HTML

```html
<a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/zgGPvJM7A98" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/zgGPvJM7A98" alt="Top-down view of blue ocean waves" width="300">
</a>
```

- Adding the `target="blank"` attribute opens it in a new tab
- Adding the `rel="nooopener noreferrer"` attribute prevents the new tab from maliciously modifying the original tab

### Answer using Adobe Acrobat

The answer can be found on their website [here](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/resources/how-to-add-hyperlink-to-pdf.html)
Following these steps

> 1. Choose Tools › Edit PDF › Link › Add or Edit. The pointer becomes a crosshair, and any existing links in the document, including invisible links, are temporarily visible.

> 2. Drag a rectangle where you want to create a link. Whether it’s a text box or graphic, this will be the area in which the link is active.

> 3. In the Create Link dialog box that appears, choose your link appearance. Make it invisible, or choose the link type and highlight
>    style, as well as the line type, style, thickness, and color.

etc..

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your answer, however, the title clearly says "without html". This is because I do not have access to the html.

Comment: @Mrs.Spangler. Okay, I'll edit to suit, but what program are you using in order to have it linked. Is it Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: I can save the image as a pdf.  It is being hosted on a marketplace and I would like to link it to a free sample that opens in a new tab so that the user won't lose the site where they can make the purchase.

Comment: So are you saying that I cannot change a link's structure to make it open in another tab unless I use html?

Comment: I think I'm having a hard time trying to understand where it is you're trying to display this image in the first place. Can you walk us through what you're trying to use to make this so-called image open in a new tab. What is this 'marketplace' you are referring to? Is it something you have created? Or is it  on an already made platform?

Comment: Yes, I can explain.  Look at the preview for this product:  https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Bell-Ringer-Mentor-Sentences-For-Middle-School-Printable-and-Digital-BUNDLE-3147816  On the last page there is a link for a free sample.  If you click on it, it opens in the same tab, taking the buyer away from the product sales page.  I would like it to open in another tab so the buyer could easily find their way back to purchase the item.

Comment: @KJ is right. However, Mrs. Spangler,  are you the one who has uploaded the pdf of the preview? If so, what did you use to make the pdf?

Comment: @Kedmun  Yes, I made the preview.  I used Adobe.

Comment: @Mrs.Spangler, is it adobe Acrobat that you're using? If so, are you able to find the version number? Also, I did put in my original answer the way to do it with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @Kedmun  Thank you - yes I did see your answer for using Adobe.  I know how to add a link, just not how to make it open in a new tab.  I have Adobe Acrobat XI Pro.