# How to fix the redirect to pdf but it return home

Tags: javascript, typescript, href

```
 <a nz-col class="my-1" [nzXl]="12" [nzLg]="12" [nzMd]="12" [nzSm]="12" [nzXs]="24" [href]="'http://example.com/shipment' + data['invoice_pdf']" target="_blank">
            <button nz-button type="button" tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-secondary">
              <i nz-icon nzType="box-plot" nzTheme="outline"></i>SHIPMENT PDF
            </button>
          </a>
```

I have a problem when I try to click the SHIPMENT PDF instead it redirect to `http://example.com/shipment/media/281738_218129shipment.pdf`, but it return to home page. how do I fix it?

Comment: This could be because the pdf file is getting downloaded

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925481/opening-a-new-tab-to-read-a-pdf-file/37779279

Comment: Typically that's the behavior of files that are not processed by browser. However, if you want it to open in next tab and show pdf then you may have to use PDF viewer control in your page and show the PDF in that.