# a href target blank sometimes stucks on about:blank

Tags: html

I am trying to open a google docs link in a new tab on browser like:

`<a href="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={some-url}" target="_blank">Google Sheet</a>`

But sometimes link does not open and stucks on about:blank page. But if I press refresh button, the link opens. What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

I tried on Chrome, Opera and Yandex browsers. All of them acts the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925481/opening-a-new-tab-to-read-a-pdf-file[Other Question][1] Look at this. It´s the same Question

Comment: @Louis not even close

Answer (score -1):

Dont use the url=
Or download the file and put it in your folder. Then set the href to open or download your pdf. Would this be a sol?

Comment: Actually, our customers have two options. One of them is downloading and another one is viewing it on google sheets. So, this is not a proper solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).