# How to display pdf from pdf url in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am working on a `iOS/Android/Web` app where I am getting a **PDF** url from server.I want to
preview pdf on flutter web in Flutter web but I am not able to preview it from url.

Comment: why don't you open the pdf link on a browser instead (for android/ios) or new tab (if web). please follow this to do the same for web: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925481/opening-a-new-tab-to-read-a-pdf-file

Comment: May be you can follow this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62476108/how-to-load-and-present-a-pdf-file-from-the-web-in-flutter

Comment: @androCoder-BD if i will use it in new tab with url it will expose the link which i don't want . However, I found my solution for that i used syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer library by using this library i can open pdf from url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this package [pdf flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)
It is a complete PDF package/solution for flutter. But you just need to look at the viewing part. See their example. Supports all the platforms.

Comment: Not supported on web?